# What are the colors in DayLight theme?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am developing an app that uses `CardView` with `RecyclerView`.

The theme is `AppCompat.DayLight`. The cards are predominately white background, and so is the recyclerview, but a bit darker than cards background, which is default,  coming from the DayNight theme, I believe.

But, I don't know the exact value or the name of these color, as I have to use those values in other places.

Can somebody kindly help me with those values?

Answer (score 1):

try this line

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yourColor"
```

in xml file you can add it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yourColor">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Edit

Try the below line of code

```
    <style name="CustomCardview1" parent="CardView">
          <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#F3921F</item>
          <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
          <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
         <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
     </style>

    <style name="CustomCardview2" parent="CardView">
          <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#F3931F</item>
          <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
          <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
         <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
     </style>
```

Write the below line of code in layout where you need the cardview

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      style="@style/CustomCardview">
```

i hope understand right

Comment: I know that. I am asking for the value used by appcompat theme.